# how to subdivide the items of a list

Tags: python, numpy

#How do I subdivide each items of a list.

My code

```
import numpy as np

org_x = [11,15,20,25]
some_list = []
for i in org_x:
    some_list.append(i/2)
print(some_list)
```

present outcome:

```
[5.5, 7.5, 10.0, 12.5]
```

Expected outcome:

```
[5.5,5.5,7.5,7.5,10.0,10.0,12.5,12.5]
```

Comment: Are you wanting this ? `np.repeat(np.asarray(org_x)/2, 2)` base tagging [tag:numpy]

Answer (score 0):

If you want each item twice, you should call `append` twice at each iteration

```py
for i in org_x:
    some_list.append(i/2)
    some_list.append(i/2)
```